# Charging expenses for an room that would otherwise stand empty

Tags: expenses

We rent an office with a certain number of rooms, and then rent rooms to projects (or working groups; independent budget entities) within the organization. One of our projects would be happy to use the extra room, but does not have the budget to pay what we would charge in tenancy fees. So the room stands empty. Basically, the rent expense of that room gets passed on to every other project in the form of indirect costs.

It feels ridiculous to maintain an empty room in the name of fairness, but that's what I'm doing. Is that just unavoidable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with navigating the workplace. It is asking whether to give a room for rent or keep it empty.

Comment: Are you there tenant or the landlord? What do you mean by "project" - some internal project team? If your company is already paying for the space, allocating room rents to individual project budgets seems to be internal charging gone crazy...

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer. @HorusKol What would be an alternative?

Comment: What sounds ridiculous is the unnecessary overhead of allocating rooms within the organization and collecting "rent" for it, which is a lot like putting money from your left pocket into your right pocket. Why not get rid of this whole rent thing and let the expenses be handled at a higher level?

Comment: Get them to have every other project sign off on free rent.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, but it does sound ridiculous nonetheless. There is no reason why a better system cannot be put in place. It isn't even that complicated to do. For example, I worked at company A where employees could take a cab to go home if they worked late (with management approval). Each employee had to pay for the cab and then get it reimbursed. Then I worked at company B, which also has similar cab policy, except that the employees just hop in and get off. The payments to the cab vendor are handled directly by the employer.

Comment: In the OP's case, they could similarly handle payments to the landlord at a higher management level, without having to collect money from every project, and the management can internally decide how to allocate rooms to each project. The end result in terms of money outflow from the company is the same, but the internal overhead on each project manager and the "rental" team is avoided. Anyway, the project doesn't pay the "rent" from its own pocket, but from the money allocated by the management, so not sure why those intermediate steps are necessary.

Comment: @MaskedMan Some companies especially those billing out allocate cost to projects.  Rent is a significant cost.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Ok here's how ... Case A: Employee pays $10 to cab. Employee submits paperwork to Dept X. Dept X gets approval from Dept Y, then forwards paperwork to Dept Z. Dept Z pays $10 to employee after several days. Net outcome: Cab vendor gets $10, employee gets to use the cab, employer spends $10. Case B: Cab vendor submits paperwork to Dept X. Dept X pays $10 to cab vendor. Outcome: Same as above, with a more productive  (and happy) employee, no unwanted forwarding = cost savings for employer. aka win-win situation.

Comment: @Paparazzi Yeah so what is what is stopping them from billing that rent directly to the "out" customer? What is the need for ... step 1: big boss "funds" project A with $1000 for "rent". step 2: project A requests rental team for a room. step 3: rental team approves the request. step 4: project A pays $1000 to rental team. step 5: project A submits "customer invoice" of $1000 (along with other expenses) to big boss. step 6: big boss approves invoice and forwards to customer. Who gains what from all those extra steps?

Comment: @MaskedMan Nothing is *stopping* them.   Some companies need that kind if cost tracking.  Let it go.

Comment: @Joe I guess the only difference with my analogy is that in that case the employee is the "customer", but the point is still the same. All those internal intermediate steps are unnecessary and can be avoided with some common sense. If the employee (or in this case, "project"), employer and the customer are treated as 3 black boxes, it is easy to see that the money flow between them shouldn't be affected by presence or absence of a "rental team" inside the employer black box. I don't say that cross-budgeting is not common, but it is extremely stupid and lazy way of moving money among adults.

Comment: @Paparazzi Certainly, I do not really care what stupid practices the OP's employer follows. I just pointed out that it is a ridiculous idea that gets in the way of business, and can be easily replaced by better ideas. There is also a bit of XY problem there. OP's employer needs to step back and consider, "what are we trying to achieve?" Do we want our customer to be happy or to follow some "internal process" meticulously? I am not sure paying rent for a room not being used *and* keeping a project hanging for the lack of a room makes a whole lot of business sense, but what do I know? :)

Comment: @MaskedMan You don't know anything about their business.   Some business track cost at a project level.   They could have different customers that don't want money commingled.   Or different capital projects.    Charging a room to a project is not much overhead.

Answer (score 3):

> It feels ridiculous to maintain an empty room in the name of fairness,
>   but that's what I'm doing. Is that just unavoidable?

I'm not sure it's a matter of "fairness".

Projects in a corporation all vie for limited budget money. Sometimes that puts them in conflict with each other.

If a project is deemed sufficiently worthy, then they are given the money to achieve their goals. If not, then they aren't given the money.

If a room remains vacant, then that says no project has been deemed worthy enough to have the funds to cover the rent. That seems fair to me.

This is more a budgeting issue, not a fairness issue.

Unless the rooms are just considered a "resource" (just like people, equipment, and dollars are "resources") and included as part of the project initiation and budgeting process through which every project must pass, then it's probably unavoidable that one or more rooms remain unoccupied on occasion.

Answer (score 0):

**Yeah, that is pretty ridiculous.** I would let them use the room until you find a "paying" internal tenant, and make it very clear to them that you're doing a favor and they may need to vacate at very short notice, and to the rest of the office that the room is still available.

Answer (score 0):

The goal should be to do what's best for the organization as a whole. Leaving one room unused when some group could very well use it is not best for the organisation as a whole.

An organization also sets up rules that should be followed. These rules should be designed so that if everyone follows the rules, the result is good for the whole organisation. Sometimes that doesn't work (like in your case). In that case, you either suffer the consequences of the rules, or you change the rules, or you introduce another rule that says when rules shouldn't be followed.

But breaking the rules may have a cost by itself. Let's say it's worth $1,000 a month for that group to get the room for free. But breaking the rule causes disruption, people complain, feel they are treated unfairly, maybe even sabotage the work of that group for revenge, and cause $2,000 a month in damage. That ridiculous refusal to give them the room may be actually the best for your company.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to use a spare room that don't benefit a single sub-group over all others.

I'd suggest putting a table, some chairs and possibly a few whiteboards and/or a projector and screen in the room.  This would turn it into a temporary conference room.

An ~300 person building at my old job had 5 or 10 smaller rooms that cycled between being small conference rooms (mostly 6-12 people), project labs, and offices for middle management as the needs of the company varied.